# Mounted only trigger once in dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `App.vue`

I'm using dynamic component to render dynamic component coming from Vuex

```
<component :is="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent"></component>
```

then in my `Home.vue`

```
<v-card @click="showDetails">
  <v-card-title primary-title>
     <div class="mb-0 text-truncate"> {{name}} </div>
  </v-card-title>
</v-card>

import Details from '@/components/UI/Details';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  methods: {
    showDetails() {
      console.log('Mount Dynamic Component');
      this.$store.commit('SET_DYNAMIC_COMPONENT', Details);
    }
  }  
}
```

then on the `Details` component

```
export default {
  name: 'Details',
  mounted: {
    console.log('This component has been mounted');
  }
}
```

The mounted lifecycle trigger only once when I click the card in `Home.vue`
I'm expecting that everytime I click the card it should print

`Mount Dynamic Component`

and

`This component has been mounted`

Comment: Have you tried using `v-on:click`?

Comment: @click is the shorthand for v-on:click

Comment: I managed to make this work. I use updated lifecycle instead mounted. But I would like to check for other solutions.

Comment: I think it's not specific to dynamic components. It's just that the component is not re-created because it's already mounted.

Comment: @jaudo I'm also assuming that. But what will be the approach if I would like to show the `This component . has been mounted` everytime I change the vuex state

Answer (score 2):

You can define in your vuex state a numeric variable (i.e. `dynamicComponentKey`) that will work as `key` for the dynamic component, and increment it in your `SET_DYNAMIC_COMPONENT` mutation.

This should force the remount of component when the key will change.

Then, in your App.vue:

```
<component :is="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent" :key="$store.getters.getDynamicComponentKey"></component>
```

Comment: I'm thinking not to add a key for each component. I tried adding random key like `Math.random()` inside :key but it only render once

Comment: because `Math.random()` is not reactive

Comment: you can just return an object from your getter where first property is key and second one is component, and have something like `<component :is="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent.comp" :key="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent.key"></component>`

Comment: Thanks @fabruex this will work If I use different component in a dynamic component. But in my example I only use component Details which will be the same. I just use updated lifecycle and detect if the dynamic component is existing. I'll post my answer. I'll upvote your answer too since it's also valid

Comment: @AllenChun Every time the key changes the component is mounted, even if the same component. I used this technique many times in my projects to force remounting. However, be careful because `updated` lifecycle is called every time a reactive property of that component changes its value. Thanks for your upvote

Comment: I would like to use key but I don't want to define key inside the state. If only this one works.
<component :is="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent.comp" :key="$store.getters.getDynamicComponent.name"></component>

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this by using updated lifecycle instead of mounted.

In `Details` component

```
export default {
  updated() {
    if (this.$store.getters.dynamicComponent) {
      console.log('This component has been mounted');
    }
  }
}
```

@fabruex solution also works but in my case I'd rather don't define another state in my vuex just for the key.